# Prevent UIScrollView from resetting contentOffset

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview

I am currently using a UIScrollView to store 2 tables side by side, similar to how Pinterest does for its Activity page. However, when I tap on the 2nd table and access a new UIViewController, going back would reset the contentOffset, hence, I'm back on the 1st table which is wrong.

Am I able to lock the contentOffset or is there other ways to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you do skmething in viewWillAppear in your first VC include UiScrollView? , you can store your current offset in view will dissappeaar

Comment: try it out with collection view , Pinterest uses collectionview

Comment: The problem is that when you go to another VC, the contentOffset will reset back to zero. I want the contentOffset to remain at the 2nd UITableView so that when I go back to the 1st VC, it will show the 2nd UITableView instead of the 1st UITableView.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this issue? I'm facing the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the UIViewController that contains the UIScrollView:

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

Comment: Still the same. When the animation begins to move to the 2nd VC, the 1st VC's UIScrollView contentOffset gets reset back to zero.

Comment: What kind of segue are you using to go from the 1st VC to the 2nd?

Comment: i'm using pushViewController

Comment: @K.Liu I just created a quick storyboard app with 2 VCs. The 1st VC has a scrollview with junk and a button to push segue to the 2nd VC. If I scroll down in the scrollview, segue to the 2nd VC, then press back to the first, my scrollview is in the same position as before I clicked the segue button.

Comment: Hi mike, how about offsetting in the x-axis. Is it the same? I have 2 uitableViews side by side.

Comment: Yep even if I scroll horizontally (x-axis) it still stays in the same positions after the segue. Are you positive it's the scrollview that is resetting? Or that you don't have some code somewhere in `viewDidLoad` that's setting the offset?

Comment: viewDidLoad only load once and also i'm not doing any reset over there. It should be scrollView contentOffset being reset (I also google on this and many people having this issue) since i saw the 1st UITableView while the 2nd VC is transitioning into the screen.

Comment: I put a breakpoint at viewWillDisappear and viewDidDisappear. What I found out is that it snap back to 1st UITableView while view is disappearing. So that means the above 2 function doesn't solve it.

Comment: Hm that's really bizarre. I can't reproduce it even when I add 2 empty prototype UITableView inside my scroll view.